# the break function only stopping what i want

Tags: python, math

```
for cal in range(1,2):
    first = (cal * 3 + 1)
    if (first % 2) == 0:
        first = first / 2
    else:
        first = (first * 3 + 1)
    for me in range(999999):
        if (first % 2) == 0:
            first = first / 2
        else:
            first = (first * 3 + 1)
        if first == 1:
            print("verified ✔")
            break
```

this program is made to cheek if a number ends up as one if a math equation happens to it.
but the problem is that at then when I say break it will completely stop. but i want it to only stop the `for me in range(999999)`.

Comment: The `break` statement is inside the inner loop, so that is the loop that will stop.  It will not stop the outer loop.  (Assuming the indentation is correct as shown.)

Comment: `for cal in range(1,2)` only runs one iteration, so when you `break` the inner loop, the program ends.

Comment: Note that in Python 3, you'll need to write `first // 2` for integerdivision

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the `break`, since the `break` breaks from the inner forloop only.

The problem is the wrong usage of the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function singe `range(1,2)` returns an iterable iterating over the value 1, hence the outer for is useless in this case since it is only running once with `cal = 1`

To understand it better you can check it with the following:

```
for value in range(1,2):
    print(value)
```

You will see that only the value 1 is printed even with no `break` statement